# Trying to write Java Method to convert infix equation to postfix

Tags: java, data-structures

Im trying to get this method to return a postfix equation (string). the precedence method requires a char and I can change it.  Is there away I ca nget this to work? First im trying to take the infix (line 44) and  for each iteration bring in a character by character of the infix and put it to the postfix. I know substring is a string method and the item variable needs to be char. Is there away I can do this or does anyone have any pointers?

```
 public static String convertToPostfix(String infix) {
 ArrayStack operator = new ArrayStack();
 char item;
 String postfix;
 Object top;

 for(int i = 0; infix.length() >= 0; i++){
  item = infix.substring(i,i);  //creates string item as one character string starting with index 0.


  if (item.toString().matches("[0..9]")){
    postfix.concat(item.toString());        //appends operand to postfix 
  }

  else if (item = "("){
     operator.push(item);
  }
  else if (item = ")"){
     top = operator.pop();
     while(top != "("){
        postfix.concat("(");
        top = operator.pop();
     }
  }
  else {
     while(!operator.isEmpty()){
        top = operator.peek();

        if(Postfix.getPrecedence(item.charValue()) <= top){
           postfix.concat(item);
           operator.pop();
        }
        else {
           break;   
        }
       operator.push(item);

     } 
  }


 }

while(!operator.isEmpty()){
  top = operator.pop();
  postfix.concat(item);

  } 

  return postfix;







}
```

Comment: [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) may be of use. Also [`Character.isDigit(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)). Also `if (item = "(")` this is a problem you need to use `==` for checking equality, as you have it it will be assigning `"("` to `item`